# Interference of light with unpolarized light

Tags: optics

If perpendicular components of an unpolarized light are brought in the same plane then interference will occur or not?

Answer (score 2):

Interference simply means that the principle of superposition of em waves is followed. It occurs in any case. However, it may not be steadily observable.

For example, if you don't have coherent sources, the light is interfering still but you can not see the interference pattern.

Now in your question you need to clarify what you mean by perpendicular components.

**Further Reference**

https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-1/Polarization

https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_relation_between_coherence_and_polarization_as_two_distinct_properties_of_light/amp

Comment: Unpolarized light have different planes of polarization and taking out two perpendicular components and bringing them in same plane will produce interference pattern or not?

Comment: So you first polarize unpolarized light.

Comment: As I explained. Interference will occur. In your specific case, what is observable is circularly or elliptical or linear polarised light depending on phase difference and amplitude of the individual waves.